# MigLayout - Making cells grow as window grows

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

[image: UI]

What I want to occur is for the eastern and southern docks to move to the edges of the window, with the two cells in the middle filling all other space.
Instead, the docks are static and stretching the window just generates empty space.

```
    setLayout(new MigLayout(""));
    treeScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    add(treeScrollPane, "growy, growx");

    displayedTree = tree;
    treeScrollPane.setViewportView(displayedTree);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    add(scrollPane, "growy");

    parentsTable = new JTable();
    parentsTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);





    scrollPane.setViewportView(parentsTable);
    parentsTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(


        new Object[][] {
        },
        new String[] {
            "Parent"
        }   
    ) 

    {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }

    });
        JPanel easternDock = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0", "", "push[]")); 

    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
... add a bunch of stuff to bottomPanel...
    easternDock.add(bottomPanel);
    Box southernDock = Box.createHorizontalBox();
... add a bunch of stuff to southernDock ...
... Do menu stuff ...
    this.add(southernDock, "dock south");
    this.add(menuBar, "dock north");
    this.add(easternDock, "dock east");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding both panes to a SplitScrollPane, and then adding it to the mainPanel with "push, grow" constraints.

```
JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                treeScrollPane, scrollPane);
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(400);
        splitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);

add(splitPane, "push, grow");
```